# Threading Stopwatches

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create 4 stopwatches that all run concurrently.  They all start when the program begins.

I want the user to be able to use the Q,W,E,R keys to speed up the stopwatches (from left to right following the keyboard pattern).  I've established pretty much everything but It wont let my press any other key but the R key to speed up the 4th clock.

I want to implement threading to allow this.  How do I go about it?

Heres the code:

```
public class Stopwatches extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {    
        Time time1 = new Time();
        Time time2 = new Time();
        Time time3 = new Time();
        Time time4 = new Time();
        Text text1 = new Text("00:00:00");
        Text text2 = new Text("00:00:00");
        Text text3 = new Text("00:00:00");
        Text text4 = new Text("00:00:00");
        text1.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));
        text2.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));
        text3.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));
        text4.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));
        Timeline textClock1 = createTextStopwatch(time1, text1);
        textClock1.play();
        Timeline textClock2 = createTextStopwatch(time2, text2);
        textClock2.play();
        Timeline textClock3 = createTextStopwatch(time3, text3);
        textClock3.play();
        Timeline textClock4 = createTextStopwatch(time4, text4);
        textClock4.play();

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
        tilePane.setPadding(new Insets(15,5,5,5));
        tilePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tilePane.setHgap(40.0);
        tilePane.getChildren().addAll(text1, text2, text3, text4);
        pane.setCenter(tilePane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1500, 400);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == Q ){
                textClock1.setRate(20.0);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == Q ){
                textClock1.setRate(1.0);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == W ){
                textClock2.setRate(20.0);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == W ){
                textClock2.setRate(1.0);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == E ){
                textClock3.setRate(20.0);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == E ){
                textClock3.setRate(1.0);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == R ){
                textClock4.setRate(20.0);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == R ){
                textClock4.setRate(1.0);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Stop Watch");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Timeline createTextStopwatch(Time time, Text text) {
        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> {
            time.increase();
            text.setText(time.toString());
        }));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        return animation;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Ive made a second attempt at implementing multithreading, but it just wont work.

```
public class Stopwatches extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {    
        Time time1 = new Time();
        Time time2 = new Time();
        Time time3 = new Time();
        Time time4 = new Time();
        Text text1 = new Text("00:00:00");
        Text text2 = new Text("00:00:00");
        Text text3 = new Text("00:00:00");
        Text text4 = new Text("00:00:00");
        text1.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));
        text2.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));
        text3.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));
        text4.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));
        Timeline textClock1 = createTextStopwatch(time1, text1);
        textClock1.play();
        Timeline textClock2 = createTextStopwatch(time2, text2);
        textClock2.play();
        Timeline textClock3 = createTextStopwatch(time3, text3);
        textClock3.play();
        Timeline textClock4 = createTextStopwatch(time4, text4);
        textClock4.play();

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
        tilePane.setPadding(new Insets(15,5,5,5));
        tilePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tilePane.setHgap(40.0);
        tilePane.getChildren().addAll(text1, text2, text3, text4);
        pane.setCenter(tilePane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1500, 400);

        Runnable task1 = new IncreaseTime(textClock1);
        Runnable task2 = new DecreaseTime(textClock1);
        Runnable task3 = new IncreaseTime(textClock2);
        Runnable task4 = new DecreaseTime(textClock2);
        Runnable task5 = new IncreaseTime(textClock3);
        Runnable task6 = new DecreaseTime(textClock3);
        Runnable task7 = new IncreaseTime(textClock4);
        Runnable task8 = new DecreaseTime(textClock4);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(task1);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(task2);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(task3);
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(task4);
        Thread thread5 = new Thread(task5);
        Thread thread6 = new Thread(task6);
        Thread thread7 = new Thread(task7);
        Thread thread8 = new Thread(task8);


        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == Q ){
                thread1.start();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == Q ){
                thread2.start();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == W ){
                thread3.start();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == W ){
                thread4.start();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == E ){
                thread5.start();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == E ){
                thread6.start();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == R ){
                thread7.start();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == R ){
                thread8.start();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Stop Watch");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Timeline createTextStopwatch(Time time, Text text) {
        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> {
            time.increase();
            text.setText(time.toString());
        }));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        return animation;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class IncreaseTime implements Runnable {
    Timeline textClock;

    public IncreaseTime(Timeline textClock) {
        this.textClock = textClock;
        }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        textClock.setRate(20.0);
    }

}

class DecreaseTime implements Runnable {
    Timeline textClock;

    public DecreaseTime(Timeline textClock) {
        this.textClock = textClock;
        }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        textClock.setRate(1.0);
    }

}
```

I forgot the show my secondary class which makes the Time objects, here it is:

```
public class Time {
    int value = 0;

    int getSecond() {
      return value % 60;
    }

    int getMinute() {
      return (value / 60) % 60;
    }

    int getHour() {
      return value / 3600;
    }  

    void reset() {
      value = 0;
    }

    void increase() {
      value++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return getTwoDigitString(getHour()) + ":" + getTwoDigitString(getMinute())
        + ":" + getTwoDigitString(getSecond());
    }

    static String getTwoDigitString(int v) {
      if (v < 10)
        return "0" + v;
      else
        return "" + v;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The app is getting all of your button presses Q,W,E,R.

Problem is that all your setOnKeyReleased methods setRate on textClock4.
So I believe you think it is only getting your R button presses.

Where it sounds like you want

```
Q to operate on textClock1
W to operate on textClock2
E to operate on textClock3
R to operate on textClock4
```

A debugging tip is add a print statement to your console from your scene on the button presses it receives. You begin breaking down and narrowing down where in your code the issue will be.

Comment: Ive fix the error you pointed out but it still only increases and decreases textClock4 when R is pressed and released.

Comment: Hey make sure to upvote correct answers to your questions. @MasterCassim hit the nail on the head. I only got back to this today.

Answer (score 0):

Your eventListeners are overriding themselfes. Use one setOnKeyPressed and on setOnKeyReleased which implements the logic with if-then-else.